# add custom footer from tex file in beamer without theme

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

I use `./footer/footer.tex` as:

```
\begin{textblock*}{127mm}(0mm,84mm)
\begin{center}
{\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont{\quad\today\hfill\raisebox{-.35cm}    {\includegraphics[height=.75cm,keepaspectratio,]{example-image-a}}\hfill University\hfill\begin{tabular}    {@{}c@{}}Presentation\\Speaker\end{tabular}\hfill sponsor\hfill\raisebox{-.35cm}        {\includegraphics[height=.75cm,keepaspectratio,]        {example-image-b}}\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}\quad}
\end{center}
\end{textblock*}
```

A new command to add:

```
\newcommand{\addfooter}{\subimport{../footer/}{footer}}
```

Adding to slide:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\printbibliography
\addfooter
\end{frame}
```

This increases slide number as well as not able to add footer in the slides that are coming automatically. To keep all in one slide properly, how to use `\only` overlay or any other idea(s)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    style=ieee,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\addfooter}{\subimport{./footer/}{footer}}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key3,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key4,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key5,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key6,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key7,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key8,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key9,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key10,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key11,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key12,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\addtolength{\textheight}{-20pt}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addfooter
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, please make your code compileable.